# Google Cloud Messaging Management Console

Tags: ios, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-platform

In [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) there is a button titled **GET A CONFIGURATION FILE** which takes you to a page titled **Enable Google Services for your app**. This page lets you select an app name - as in, app names that appear in [Google Developer Console Projects](https://console.developers.google.com/project) - and associate it with an iOS bundle identifier. You then press a button to **Choose and configure services** which gives you an API key and server ID and allows you to upload the APNS (Apple Push Notification Service) production and development certificates.

Once I do this, back in [Google Developer Console Projects](https://console.developers.google.com/project) I can see the newly generated API key under *Credentials*. However, I do see any mention of the iOS bundle identifier I just associated with that key nor do I see the APNS certificates I uploaded.

Is there a management console for Google Cloud Messaging that let's me see the API key, associated iOS bundle identifiers, and APNS certificates and also allows me to update the APNS certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less than ideal (and hopefully someone else has a better answer), but I found you can get back to the API key, server ID, and APNS certificate list by:

1. Go back to the [Setting up a GCM Client App on iOS](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client) page.
2. Click the *GET A CONFIGURATION FILE* button.
3. Select your Google Cloud Platform project and iOS bundle ID.
4. Click the *Choose and configure services* button.

If you've previously configured Google Cloud Messaging for that *Google Cloud Platform app, iOS bundle ID* pair, then the existing entry will be displayed.